# How to convert cell array of matrices into a column matrix in MATLAB?

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I have a cell array of matrices which look like this:

```
G = 
Columns 1 through 6
    [507x1 double]    [255x1 double]    [130x1 double]    [67x1 double]    [36x1 double]    [19x1 double]

Columns 7 through 9
    [11x1 double]    [6x1 double]    [4x1 double]
```

This means that the matrices are inside a cell array.  Matrix `G` has a total of 507+255+130+67+36+19+11+6+4=1035 elements in it. I can extract any cell by using the `G{i}` command. However, I need all of these 1035 elements in single column or row matrix. I have tried `cell2mat(G)` but that doesn't work.

What can I do here to create a single matrix that contains all of these other matrices together?

Comment: In what way does `cell2mat` not work? [This Gist](https://gist.github.com/sco1/55a94dad862811aba859) functions as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`cat`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cat.html) for that and concatenate vertically, or along the first dimension:

```
G = cat(1, G{:});
```

The syntax `G{:}` produces what is known as a [comma-separated list](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html).  This would be equivalent to you doing:

```
G = cat(1, G{1}, G{2}, ..., G{9});
```

Instead of you having to type in all of the individual cell elements to be used for concatenation, doing `G{:}` unpacks all of that for you.

## Minor Note

`cell2mat` essentially performs `cat` in the fashion that I talked about above.  If you look at the source for `cell2mat`, it's bloated with a lot of sanity checks, but the heart of the function is simply using `cat` and taking advantage of comma-separated lists.  I don't know why `cell2mat` wouldn't work for you.

Comment: Assuming the error is because his cell array is multidimensionial and cannot be converted to a rectangular array, an intermediate `reshape(G, 1, []);` call should suffice.

Comment: @excaza yes that would definitely work, but the verbose output given in the OP's post shows that all of the cell elements are column vectors. Still a very good observation!